# Crop image to variable in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, crop

I'm creating an app that detects faces and classifies faces' ethnicity using 2 Clarifai APIs. The issue is ethnicity classifier can only do 1 face for 1 photo. My solution is cropping the faces by face detection and then separately classify each face's ethnicity.

Then I got stuck with an idea: I want to crop the face by the coordination provided by the face detection and save the faces to variables, so I can use ethnicity classifier for each face.

I would love to receive some help from you guys. Thank you.

Here is the code of my issue

```
   this.setState({imageURL: this.state.input});
   app1.models
     .predict(
       {
         id: 'ethnicity-demographics-recognition',
         name: 'appearance-multicultural',
         version: 'b2897edbda314615856039fb0c489796',
         type: 'visual-classifier',
       },
       this.state.input
     )
     .then((response) => console.log('ethnic',response))
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log("Clarifai Error:", err);
     });

   app2.models
     .predict(
       {
         id: 'face-detection',
         name: 'face-detection',
         version: '6dc7e46bc9124c5c8824be4822abe105',
         type: 'visual-detector',
       }, this.state.input)
     .then((response) => {
       const regions = response.outputs[0].data.regions;
       const box = [];
       regions.forEach(region => {
         box.push(this.calculateFaceLocation(region))
       });
       this.displayFaceBox(box);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log("Clarifai Error:", err);
     });
```

I looked up some solution like HTML canvas and react-image-crop, but I am still unable to save the faces as variables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part of code will not show the way you handling the file from your input. I think you may need to use browser api first of all. The you can use 'faceapi' npm package, or Cloudinary for instance to crop the image and then handle the ethnicity with your methods in  Clarifai APIs.
But first of all console.log is our best friend ;)

```
<input
  type='file'
  onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.files[0])}
/>
```